# If $ A=B^{-1}C\left( B+C\right) ^{-1}BC^{-1}\left( B+C\right) $, then $ A^{2}=I_{n} $

Tags: matrices

If $B,C\in M_{n}\left( R\right) ,\det B\neq 0,\det C\neq 0 , \det \left( B+C\right) \neq 0$ and $ A=B^{-1}C\left( B+C\right) ^{-1}BC^{-1}\left( B+C\right) $, then $ A^{2}=I_{n} $

By calculating $A^{2}$ I’ve found $ A^{2}=A $, but I cannot go longer...

Answer (score 4):

Expanding the second half, we get
$$
BC^{-1}(B+C) = BC^{-1}B + BC^{-1}C \\
= BC^{-1}B + B\\
= BC^{-1}B + CC^{-1}B\\
= (B+C)C^{-1}B
$$
which means that we have
$$
A = B^{-1}C(B+C)^{-1}(B+C)C^{-1}B = I
$$